# Gazebo installation problem on Windows

Tags: gazebo, installation, windows10, errors, gz-sim

I'm trying to install Gazebo on Windows 10 following these steps:
https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_windows_src

I have completed all the steps in the "Install dependencies" section without any errors.
In the "Building the Gazebo Libraries" section, when I try to build the libraries with the command: `colcon build --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF --merge-install --packages-up-to gz-sim8 gz-tools2`,

it outputs:

```
Summary: 15 packages finished [7min 34s]
  5 packages had stderr output: gz-fuel_tools9 gz-math7 gz-rendering8 gz-sim8 sdformat14
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)*
```

and when I try to run the server with the command: `gz sim -s -v`,
I get:

```
Library error for [D:/miniforge3/condabin/gz-ws/install/bin/gz-sim8-gz.dll]: Exec format error*
```

and the server doesn't start.

Any ideas what is wrong and how it can be fixed?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: We would need to check what kind of binary is the gz-sim8-gz.dll, seems incompatible with your system. On Windows two alternatives: TRID https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html could give us a hint or install Git and use Git Bash to run: "file  D:/miniforge3/condabin/gz-ws/install/bin/gz-sim8-gz.dll". Please attach the output to your question so we know what kind of binary it is.

Comment: Hello Jose, thanks for the comment.

Git bash output: "D:/miniforge3/condabin/gz-ws/install/bin/gz-sim8-gz.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows, 6 sections".

TrID output: "Collecting data from file: D:/miniforge3/condabin/gz-ws/install/bin/gz-sim8-gz.dll
 48.7% (.EXE) Win64 Executable (generic) (10523/12/4)
 23.3% (.EXE) Win16 NE executable (generic) (5038/12/1)
  9.3% (.EXE) OS/2 Executable (generic) (2029/13)
  9.2% (.EXE) Generic Win/DOS Executable (2002/3)
  9.2% (.EXE) DOS Executable Generic (2000/1)"

Comment: Seems like a 64bits binary to my eyes. Unless you have a 32bits Windows running or you are trying to launch gz-sim from a UNIX like environment inside Windows I can not tell much more. You might need to debug it using a runtime debugger (MSVC?)

Comment: I see, Jose. Anyway, thanks for your time. I will try to reinstall everything.